# VirtualBox error (0x1)

Tags: macos, error, virtualbox

I am trying to install Ubuntu on Virtual Box instead of Parallels for a change. However VirtualBox was being a little problematic.

- First during the installation **it finished with "Could not complete Installation"**
- I ignored this later to **find VirtualBox still in the** `/Applications` folder**
- I opened it and it worked. So I **created a VM for Ubuntu.**

When I had finished creating I clicked *Start* and was instantly given an error code 1:
[image: error code given when attempted to run]

I gave this error a *Google Search* however I only found **fixes for Windows and Ubuntu**. I am running *OS X Mavericks* and so this registry edits wouldn't be available on *OS X*.

---

One fix that I found was available on Ask Ubuntu.
[image: Link to question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/122211/getting-error-message-when-trying-to-start-a-virtual-machine]
*https://askubuntu.com/questions/122211/getting-error-message-when-trying-to-start-a-virtual-machine*

*Sunil J* had the same error as me however managed to get a fix it on Ubuntu. Is there a fix for OS X and if so what is it.

*Note: I have already tried reinstalling*

Versions:

- [OS X Mavericks - 10.9.5](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1760)
- [Virtual Box 5.0.6](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

Comment: @bmike I cant remember the exact one all i remember is it was 32bit but which one would you recommend me to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30443/discussion-between-bmike-and-racing121).